# How to manage login using google sign in

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, authentication, google-signin

I have used google sign in in my app and i have another login option in my app too, i have stored data and used it in other view with the help of following code :

```
    //stored data
    NSUserDefaults *storage = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [storage setObject:userId forKey:@"email"];
    [storage setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [storage synchronize];

    //retrieved data in other view
      NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      e_mail.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"email"];
      NSString *naam=[defaults objectForKey:@"name"];
```

when i run app,i automatically displays email id of  google,even if i have not signed in using google.
it's a trouble,can someone help me ?

Comment: when you signed out ... had you remove your user defaults???

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 No.. how to do that ?

Comment: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"email"];`  .. same for other objects that saved in userdefaults

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 alright ! thank you so much :-)

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 it's working :)

Comment: great ... happy coding :)